# How do I beat Nemesis in Resident Evil: The Umbrella Chronicles?

Tags: resident-evil-umbrella

With Jill and Carlos, fighting to the roof before Racoon City goes up in flames, Nemesis is trying to kill me.

How do I get his life bar down faster then mine? I keep shooting his head but his tentacles are dealing far too much damage.

Answer (score 1):

In this video, I think about 4 minutes in, is the part you're talking about:

They seem to be employing a rocket launcher rather liberally.

If you haven't got a rocket launcher, use the Submachine Gun.  If he grabs you, shoot him quickly to get him to let go.  When his tentacles burrow into the ground, it's better to ignore them and focus on his head.  The time you'd take to deal with them generally isn't worth the effort compared to doing damage.  If he leaps at you, dodge and then fire on him while he's stunned.  The head's definitely his weak point.